# I am unable to display image from Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[My Firebase Cloud database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIXLK.png)

My Activity Code

```
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore  = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference collectionReference;
private void getData() {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mobileNumber = currentUser.getPhoneNumber();

    collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("OWNERS_DATA");
    query = collectionReference.document(mobileNumber).collection("BUILDING_DATA");

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<AddBuilding> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<AddBuilding>()
            .setQuery(query, AddBuilding.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new OwnerBuildingListAdapter(options);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

In My Pojo class I have given an empty constructor, constructor, getter and setter.
Im getting the error at .setquery(query, AddBuilding.class) line.
My Adapter Class Looks like this.

```
public class OwnerBuildingListAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<AddBuilding, OwnerBuildingListAdapter.OwnerBuildingListHolder> {
public OwnerBuildingListAdapter(FirestoreRecyclerOptions<AddBuilding> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(OwnerBuildingListHolder ownerBuildingListHolder, int i, AddBuilding addBuilding) {

    ownerBuildingListHolder.buildingName.setText(addBuilding.getBuildingName());
    String imageUrl = addBuilding.getImageUrl();
    Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(ownerBuildingListHolder.buildingImage);

}

@NonNull
@Override
public OwnerBuildingListHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_cardview, parent, false);
    return new OwnerBuildingListHolder(view);
}

class OwnerBuildingListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView buildingName;
    ImageView buildingImage;

    public OwnerBuildingListHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        buildingName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        buildingImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    }
}
}
```

If I run the program I am getting the output but not getting Image

Can u Help me o Solve this

Answer (score 1):

Update the firestore ui dependency to the latest version:

```
    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.0.2'
```

Check here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: image is not getting

Comment: I Have changed the version. Now i am getting data

Comment: But image not getting